# Measure local TCP traffic between two processes

Tags: tcp, network-traffic

Let's say I have two local processes running on my computer, `client` and `server`. They have TCP-connection on particular port, and I see it using `sudo tcptrack -i lo`:

```
Client             Server             State         ...
127.0.0.1:43832    127.0.0.1:42999    ESTABLISHED   ...
```

How can I measure the real network traffic (in bytes) between `client` and `server`?

Comment: `ss -i` is your friend